# Sharing credentials between two android applications

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3

I have two applications. If one application is already installed on Android. The second application should use the credentials of the first application. How can I achieve sharing app credentials in Android?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by 'app credentials'? Are they just something you stored in a shared preference in the first app? If so, then you can use the 'android:sharedUserId' attribute in the manifest. If both apps have the same sharedUserId, they can read each other's shared preferences.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, update the manifest of both of your apps to look like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.yourpackage.firstapp" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.0" 
android:sharedUserId="com.your.userId">


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.yourpackage.secondapp" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.0" 
android:sharedUserId="com.your.userId">
```

Now let's say in your first app, you save the username/password as SharedPrefs or some xml file. When second app launches, it can now have access to the private directory of the first app, by looking for the sharedprefs file at /data/data/com.yourpackage.firstapp/shared_prefs/

If the first app's shared_prefs path exists, then you can open it and read the user/pass credentials.

Comment: what happens when one of the app gets uninstalled ?